# How can i achieve full screen swipe functionality,even over buttons in my android app?

Tags: java, android, xml, touch, swipe

I set my layout to be on touch listener using the following code

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)          
    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup ourView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.play, null);

    setContentView(ourView);

    ourView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

I also have a 5*5 grid of buttons that take a significant amount of space and are set to on click listener.
What i want is when i swipe right, do some stuff to the grid, same with left,up and down 
Everything works fine when i swipe in the region where the grid is not placed , but whenever  i swipe over the buttons my touch is not detected.
How to correct it ?
I tried using a frame layout, and setting an empty layout over my layout of the grid,and setting the upper layout to on touch listener, but it didnt work.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    transi.clear();
    transj.clear();
    TextView debug = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdebug);

    switch (arg1.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        sx = arg1.getX();
        String y = Float.toString(sx);

        debug.setText("in" + y);
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        fx = arg1.getX();

        String x = Float.toString(fx);

        // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        int st = (int) sx;
        int fin = (int) fx;
        int diff = fin - st;
        debug.setText("st" + st + "fin" + fin + "diff" + diff);
        if (fin != 0) {

            if (fin > st) {

                moveright();
                debug.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

                display();
                singleplayer();

            } else if (fin < st) {

                moveleft();

                display();
                singleplayer();

            }
        }

        // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        sx = 0;
        fx = 0;
        st = 0;
        fin = 0;
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the implementation of your touch listener?

Comment: @helleye Added the onTouch method, in the edited question